# how to set environment variables from a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I'm trying to set environment variable through a shell script. Here is the script with various techniques:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "export SOMEPATH=/root/some" >> /root/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$SOMEPATH/bin" >> /root/.bash_profile
SOMEPATH=/root/some
export SOMEPATH
source /root/.bash_profile
```

I run the script `a.sh` with `sh a.sh`

Then if I check the `env` variable it doesn't show up.

`echo $SOMEPATH` returns nothing. I expected to get `SOMEPATH` returned